# Use Less mixins directly in HTML?

Tags: html, css, dom, less

Can I use the LESS mixins directly in the HTML? For example, this is my LESS mixin.

```
.padding(@size){
padding: @size;
}
```

Can I call this in HTML like

```
<div class="padding(0)"></div>
```

Comment: @Pete Less doesn't have to be compiled on the server side, it can works in the browser too like shown on their home page.

Comment: Considering you already type the code just try running it and you will see. Probably take less time than waiting for the answer. But if it's not in the doc then it's probably not supported.

Comment: Ah @GillesC never knew that, I've only ever used it precompiled - I would have thought doing it on the fly like that would be a bit of a performance hit

Comment: Well, Less can work in a browser but this does not add any new browser specific functionality, it's still completely *pre*-build thing. So the answer to your question: "No, you can't".

Comment: @GillesC, I tried it, it didn't work, I am asking for a workaround.

Comment: @seven-phases-max should make this an answer, as there really is no way current HTML can do what is being asked. There isn't a workaround as the mixins themselves are not available/callable/useable once the CSS is compiled.

Comment: Well, I think the proper answer would be "Learn about vanilla HTML styling e.g. `<div style="padding: 0"></div>` and don't pollute your code with redundant garbage (you don't need any CSS for above use-case *at all*).

Comment: @seven-phases-max, this was just a dummy question, to understand the logic and see if it can work. No problem, I understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial on Less Mixins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/less/less_mixins.htm)

Example
The following example demonstrates the use of mixins in the LESS file −

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css" type = "text/css" />
      <title>LESS Mixins</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1>Welcome to Tutorialspoint</h1>
      <p class = "p1">LESS is a CSS pre-processor that enables customizable, 
      manageable and reusable style sheet for web site.</p>
      <p class = "p2">LESS is a dynamic style sheet language that extends the capability of CSS.</p>
      <p class = "p3">LESS is cross browser friendly.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Next, create the style.less file.

```
style.less

.p1 {
   color:red;
}

.p2 {
   background : #64d9c0;
   .p1();
}

.p3 {
   background : #LESS520;
  .p1;
}
```

You can compile the style.less to style.css by using the following command −

lessc style.less style.css
Execute the above command; it will create the style.css file automatically with the following code −

```
style.css

.p1 {
   color: red;
}

.p2 {
   background: #64d9c0;
   color: red;
}

.p3 {
   background: #LESS520;
   color: red;
}
```

Output
Follow these steps to see how the above code works −

Save the above html code in the less_mixins.html file.

Open this HTML file in a browser, the following output will get displayed.